# How to pass object from Adapter to ViewPager

Tags: java, android

I have FloatingActionButton Button on XML layout_item,
all items of layout binding here in the adapter and showing in ViewPager of activity,
when binding FAB in Activity class the app crashed
how to pass this FAB from Adapter to Activity to set click listener?

the Adapter:

```
public class SliderPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     Context context;
    private List<Slide> slideList;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View slideLayout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_item,null);
        ImageView slideImage=slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_img);
        TextView slideTitle=slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_title);
        floatingActionButton=slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        slideImage.setImageResource(slideList.get(position).getImage());
        slideTitle.setText(slideList.get(position).getTitle());
        container.addView(slideLayout);
        return slideLayout;

    }

}
```

Comment: You should not pass FAB to the activity. Instead you can use an interface to connect / execute your function from adapter

Answer (score 0):

From your activity you can add this line after setAdapter line

```
viewPager.post(() -> {
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == pos) {
                adapter.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> doSomething();
            }
        });
```

doSomething() is the method you want called on click of the floatingActionButton.
pos is the position of the layout in the ViewPager. If you have just one layout pos = 0